# How to show projects not containing a given string in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, measures

I'm using sonarqube 4.5.1. Is it possible to show, in measures tab, sub-projects not containing a string?
For example, I want to show only projects not having the word "tests" in their name.

Comment: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Question-about-measures-td5032498.html